# Convert Image into Pdf using itextsharp in c#

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I want to use itextsharp to convert a page that contain the image and gridview into pdf form. Below is my code

```
  string attachment = "attachment; filename=Report.pdf";
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        StringWriter stw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htextw = new HtmlTextWriter(stw);
        divText.RenderControl(htextw);   //image is place inside 
        GridView1.RenderControl(htextw);           
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, Response.OutputStream);
        document.Open();
        StringReader str = new StringReader(stw.ToString());
        HTMLWorker htmlworker = new HTMLWorker(document);
        htmlworker.Parse(str);
        document.Close();
        Response.Write(document);
        Response.End();
```

i managed to convert the gridview into pdf but unable to convert the image. The image is place inside the div call divText. Does anyone can help me in this?

Comment: How is the image referenced? Base64-URL? Relative URL? Absolute URL?

Comment: Unrelated but remove the line `Response.Write(document);` which literally calls `ToString()` on the `Document` object which doesn't override the default so you are literally writing the text `iTextSharp.text.Document` to the end of every file and will eventually end up with a corrupt PDF.

Comment: Back to the question, we need to see an abbreviated version of `stw.ToString()` because `HTMLWorker` only works with HTML, not GridViews, and that's all that matters.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to try following code and modify according to you

```
public static void ConvertImageToPdf(string srcFilename, string dstFilename)
    {
        iTextSharp.text.Rectangle pageSize = null;

        using (var srcImage = new Bitmap(srcFilename))
        {
            pageSize = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(0, 0, srcImage.Width, srcImage.Height);
        }
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(pageSize, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms).SetFullCompression();
            document.Open();
            var image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(srcFilename);
            document.Add(image);
            document.Close();

            File.WriteAllBytes(dstFilename, ms.ToArray());
        }
    }
```

Also refer [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30523645/converting-images-to-pdf-with-itextsharp-preserve-clipping-path)

Explanation of code above [click here](https://alandjackson.wordpress.com/2013/09/27/convert-an-image-to-a-pdf-in-c-using-itextsharp/)

[working with images itextsharp](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/87/itextsharp-working-with-images)

Comment: I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error on getinstance.

Comment: Please note that Bitmap is not available on non-windows environment
https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/system-drawing-common-windows-only

Answer (score 0):

Change the image URL path like  "C:\images\Filename.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

Your code sample looks good, *but* it's missing an implementation of `IImageProvider`. By default, `HTMLWorker` can **only** handle images with absolute URLs. So here's a simple implementation to get you started:

```
// handle <img> tags in any System.Web.UI.Control (GridView) with:
// 1. base64 Data URI scheme - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme
// 2. relative URLs on local server
// 3. absolute URLs on a remote/local server (DEFAULT)
public class ImageHander : IImageProvider
{
    public string BaseUri { get; set; }
    public static Regex Base64 = new Regex(
        @"^data:image/(?<mediaType>[^;]+);base64,(?<data>.*)",
        RegexOptions.Compiled
    );

    // alias: using iTextImage = iTextSharp.text.Image;
    public iTextImage GetImage(string src,
        IDictionary<string, string> attrs,
        ChainedProperties chain,
        IDocListener doc)
    {
        Match match;
        // [1]
        if ((match = Base64.Match(src)).Length > 0)
        {
            return iTextImage.GetInstance(
                Convert.FromBase64String(match.Groups["data"].Value)
            );
        }

        // [2]
        if (!src.StartsWith("http", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            src = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(
                new Uri(new Uri(BaseUri), src).AbsolutePath
            ); 
        }
        return iTextImage.GetInstance(src);
    }
}
```

Then you use the implementation in the code behind like this (button event handler):

```
protected void ProcessHtml(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=table.pdf");
    using (Document document = new Document())
    {
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, Response.OutputStream);
        document.Open();

        var html = new StringBuilder();
        using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter(html))
        {
            using (var htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
            {
                // replace 'ConvertControlToPdf' with **YOUR** GridView control Id!
                ConvertControlToPdf.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
            }
        }

        var providers = new Dictionary<string, Object>();
        // HTMLWorker does **NOT** understand relative URLs, so
        // make existing ones in HTML source absolute, and handle 
        // base64 Data URI schemes
        var ih = new ImageHander() { BaseUri = Request.Url.ToString() };

        // dictionary key 'img_provider' is **HARD-CODED**, in 
        // iTextSharp 5.0.0 - 5.0.5, so you may need to use next line
        // providers.Add("img_provider", ih);
        providers.Add(HTMLWorker.IMG_PROVIDER, ih);
        //            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - constant added in 5.0.6
        using (var sr = new StringReader(html.ToString()))
        {
            foreach (IElement element in HTMLWorker.ParseToList(
                sr, null, providers))
            {
                PdfPTable table = element as PdfPTable;
                document.Add(element);
            }
        }
    }
    Response.End();
}
```

Not sure what version of iTextSharp your running, so make note on the inline comments regarding the `HTMLWorker.IMG_PROVIDER` `const` above.

Answer (score 0):

To follow my comment on [Pushkar Phule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34869645/12377747)'s answer, here is the solution using an other library working on non-windows environment (SkiaSharp)

```
    using itextSharp.text;
    using itextSharp.text.pdf;
    using SkiaSharp;

    ...

    private byte[] ConvertImageToPdf(byte[] file)
    {
        var bitmap = SKBitmap.Decode(file);

        Rectangle pageSize = new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);

        using var ms = new MemoryStream();
        var document = new Document(pageSize, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms).SetFullCompression();
        document.Open();
        var image = Image.GetInstance(new MemoryStream(file));
        document.Add(image);
        document.Close();

        return ms.ToArray();
    }
```